# How to Varnish a second cache to specific IP

Tags: varnish

I have a competitor stealing our content and due to some sleuthing I found their IP address in our logs. Does anyone know how I can serve up our site to them from a second stale cache using Varnish? I want them to get the site but just old content.

I'm not even sure if this would work but here is what I came up with using the Varnish 3 reverence page. Would my go at it here do the trick?

```
backend longcache {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "8080";
  .connect_timeout = 6s;
  .first_byte_timeout = 3s;
  .between_bytes_timeout = 3s;
}

acl longcachegroup {
  "255.255.255.255";      // the bad ip
}

if (client.ip ~ longcachegroup) {
  set req.backend = longcache;

  sub vcl_fetch {
if (req.url ~ "^/*") {
    unset beresp.http.cookie;
}

# A TTL of Long ass time minutes
    set beresp.ttl = 999999999999s;
 }
}
```

Here is my current default.vcl

```
backend default {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "8080";
  .connect_timeout = 600s;
  .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
  .between_bytes_timeout = 600s;
}

sub vcl_recv {
  # Add a unique header containing the client address
  remove req.http.X-Forwarded-For;
  set    req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
}


sub vcl_recv {

# A configuration file specific for Drupal 7 that also seems to work on Drupal 6

# Either the admin pages or the login
if (req.url ~ "/admin/?") {
        # Don't cache, pass to backend
        return (pass);
}

#for anonymous search and poll votes
if (req.request ~ "POST") {
  return (pass);
}




# Remove the "has_js" cookie
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "has_js=[^;]+(; )?", "");

# Remove the "Drupal.toolbar.collapsed" cookie
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "Drupal.toolbar.collapsed=[^;]+(; )?", "");


# Remove any Google Analytics based cookies
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__utm.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

# Remove the Quant Capital cookies (added by some plugin, all __qca)
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__qc.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

# Are there cookies left with only spaces or that are empty?
if (req.http.cookie ~ "^ *$") {
        unset req.http.cookie;
}

# Static content unique to the theme can be cached (so no user uploaded images)
if (req.url ~ "^/themes/" && req.url ~ "\.(css|js|png|gif|jp(e)?g)") {
        unset req.http.cookie;
}
# Cache images
if (req.url ~ "^/files/" && req.url ~ "\.(css|js|png|gif|jp(e)?g)") {
        unset req.http.cookie;
}





# Normalize Accept-Encoding header (straight from the manual: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/vary.html)
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg)$") {
                # No point in compressing these
                remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
                set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
                set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
                # unkown algorithm
                remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
}

# Don't cache the install, update or cron files in Drupal
if (req.url ~ "install\.php|update\.php|cron\.php|current\.html|^/user|fupload/flash|stream\.html") {
    return (pass);
}

# Uncomment this to trigger the vcl_error() subroutine, which will HTML output you some variables (HTTP 700 = pretty debug)
#error 700;

# Anything else left?
if (!req.http.cookie) {
        unset req.http.cookie;
}


if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
  # Not cacheable by default
  return (pass);
}

# Try a cache-lookup
return (lookup);

}


sub vcl_fetch {

# For static content related to the theme, strip all backend cookies
if (req.url ~ "^/themes/" && req.url ~ "\.(css|js|png|gif|jp(e?)g)") {
    unset beresp.http.cookie;
}

# A TTL of 15 minutes
    set beresp.ttl = 900s;
}

sub vcl_error {

    set obj.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    set obj.http.Retry-After = "5";
    synthetic {"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>"} + obj.status + " " + obj.response + {"</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Error "} + obj.status + " " + obj.response + {"</h1>
    <p>"} + obj.response + {"</p>
    <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
    <p>XID: "} + req.xid + {"</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Varnish cache server</p>
  </body>
</html>
"};

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would be overwriting your ttl in the cache for everyone like that since it will get the same hash as the one you are targetting.

What you would need to do as well is to also add something like:

```
sub vcl_hash {

    ### these 2 entries are the default ones used for vcl. Below we add our own.
    set req.hash += req.url;
    set req.hash += req.http.host;

    if (client.ip ~ longcachegroup) {
        set req.hash += "longcachegroup";
    }
}
```